# How to merge two array of time in (hh:mm:ss) in ascending order into one combined array in Excel? Without using VBA

Tags: excel, merge

I am new to stackoverflow, do forgive me if I had made any error in presenting my question.

My current data in excel is as displayed in the screenshot.

How to combine two array in time format `hh:mm:ss` into one single array in ascending order

[image]

Basically I would like merge `column (C)` and `column (D)` into one single `column (E)` in an ascending order. The Data are all in time format `hh:mm:ss`

I understand that some of you may suggest using the filtering options but I have some constraint in the excel spreadsheet and the filtering option in excel does not really work out for time format values.

Looking forward to the community's solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Are these true times or text? What is your expected output? Is it about 22 hours and some minutes?

Comment: Hi Andreas, it is currently in (hh:mm:ss) format in excel. My output is i want to combine column C and Column D into Column E and sort it by ascending order of (hh:mm:ss) and Yes, it is about 22 hours and some minutes and some seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Only Add two colums time?

Comment: Hi Harun, apologize for not being clear on my output. Basically, what i would like to do it is to LIST column C and column D into one single column on Column E and sort them accordingly to chronologically order.  Meaning cell D9 (11:01:20) from column D should appear first, followed by cell C9 (11:01:41) from column C and thereafter. Hope this clarifies. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If they are true times then you can just use simple addition.
E8:

```
D8+C8
```

Then just set the format of the cell to a custom format of `[h]:mm:ss`, which means it will go past 24 hours when summing it.